# Html button click and nodejs in javascript

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, node-fetch

I have created app.js to start the server which also have code for calling front end html page.
In html, I have added click event where it calls another js file ex. myAccountForm.js, in this file I want to use expressjs for happening some functionality, How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have express as your web framework, add a route there, which would listen to the click from you front end. 
So when you click on that button, - it will invoke a function in your front side JS, which would call this route at your express server. Lets say the route is '/getaccountform' which is a GET.
Add this route as

```
app.get('/getaccountform',(req,res)=>{
//call the function in myAccountForm.js,
});
```

in myAccountForm.js, write your function say getMyAccountForm(), and expose it by attaching it to module.exports. like

```
module.exports.getMyAccountForm=getMyAccountForm;
```

require myAccountForm.js, where your route is written like

var myAccountForm=require('path to your myAccountForm.js');

So your code should be like

```
 var myAccountForm=require('path to your myAccountForm.js');

 app.get('/getaccountform',(req,res)=>{
     getMyAccountForm(req,res);
 });
```

Handle the request and response in your getaccountform.js
I hope this makes sense and works for you. If not, please add more details about your issue